# Birkhoff sum converges

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am master student.I have been starting to learn Ergodic theory.

Let $(X,A,\mu,T)$ be a measure-preserving dynamical system.

**Birkhoff Ergodic theorem**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}g(T^{i}(x))$$
(is called Birkhoff average of $g$) for every $g\in L^{1}(\mu)$ converges a.e.(every where if $g$ is continuous)

I have the following question:

Do we have thereom like Birkhoff ergodic theorem such that it say Birkhoff sum converges every where?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Mean_ergodic_theorem

Comment: @DanRust ,Mean Ergodic theorem deals with the $L^{2}$limiting behaviour of Birkhoff avreges for $g \in L^{2}$,what does it relate to Birkhoff sum?

Comment: You asked for a theorem *like* Birkhoff. In order to beat Birkhoff (for instance being valid for all $x$) you're going to have to weaken some conditions, such as the class of allowed functions. The Mean ergodic theorem is one such way.

Comment: Yes,That is true,But i asked a theorem like Birkhoff theorem for Birkhoff sum NOT Birkhoff averges.Do you know such a theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the system $(X,A,\mu,T)$ is ergodic.  The a. e. convergence of the Birkhoff sums would require $\int g\, d\mu = 0$.  But, even under this assumption we do not need to have convergence a.e.

Namely, Ulrich Krengel in his 1978 paper [On the speed of convergence in the ergodic theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01300052) proved that for any ergodic measure preserving invertible transformation $T$ on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and any positive sequence $\alpha_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ one can find (even a continuous) function $g$, with $\int g\, d\lambda = 0$, and such that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\alpha_n} \biggl\lvert \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} g(T^i(x)) \biggr\rvert = \infty
$$
almost everywhere.  Taking $\alpha_n=1/n$ we have
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\, \biggl\lvert \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} g(T^i(x)) \biggr\rvert = \infty
$$
almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please give an example such that the satisfy on it?

Comment: You can see an example in Krengel's paper (as the author mentioned, the main point is that $T$ is aperiodic). Perhaps there are simpler examples: I do not know.